# How to get error if FTP server is invalid.?

Tags: php, ftp, remote-access, ftp-server

I am trying to connect FTP Server ushin php code, 
if i put FTP-Servaer Name Invalid then its end the script and not return false in $conn_id.

code spinet:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($_POST['ftp_server']);
if($conn_id)
{
   echo "invalid server name";
}
else
{
   if(ftp_login($conn_id, $_POST['ftp_username'], $_POST['ftp_password']))
   {
    $connection_status = 'tested';
    echo "<script>alert('Correct FTP login credentials');</script>";
   }
}
```

its stop script at first line and not shows echo "invalid server name";

**error**

ftp_connect() [function.ftp-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

i need to alert user if he puts invalid server-name. Thanks !!!

Comment: Is it an error, or is it a warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this and you done

```
$conn = @ftp_connect("ftp.funnybunnyvideos.in");
if($conn)
{
    echo 'server name is valid';
}
else
{
    echo 'server name is invalid';
}
```

Cheers !!!

Comment: am glad to help you Mr. @Hari

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just need to change `if($conn_id)` to `if($conn_id === FALSE)`

***EDIT***

Try running this:

```
<?php
$c = ftp_connect('ftp.mozilla.org');
var_dump($c);

$c = ftp_connect('abcdefg');
var_dump($c);
?>
```

You should get this:

> resource(2) of type (FTP Buffer)  Warning: ftp_connect()
>
> [function.ftp-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
> No such host is known. in C:\abc\def.php on line 5
>
> bool(false)

Comment: I also tried it. its not working, script dead at first line with above mention error. so if condition never executed.

Comment: am also tried this,
`$conn_id = ftp_connect($_POST['ftp_server']) or die('invalid server name');`

its also shows above mention error, and die part not shows msg.

Comment: Did you get the EXACT same output as my example?

Comment: No worries. Careful using the @ operator though, its only hiding the problem. I don't think your script was stopping, otherwise in my example you wouldn't see the last line `bool(false)`. Anyway, I'm glad you found a solution that worked for you.