# Cannot connect to ftp through PHP

Tags: php, apache, ftp

I have migrated my code from xampp to lamp recently. Since that time I have a problem with ftp_connect function and it always returns false. Here is the code:

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
```

Is there any setting in PHP or apache I have to set in advanced!?

Comment: is the module enabled on lamp?

Comment: Which module do you mean?

Comment: The `ftp_connect`  always issues a warning when fails. What is it?

Comment: It just returns FALSE. No warning is appeared.

Comment: Where do you connect to? What is the `$ftp_server`?

Answer (score 2):

This example works for me:

```
$ftp_server = "SERVER IP";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$ftp_user_name = "YOUR USERNAME";
$ftp_user_pass = "YOUR PASSWORD";
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '/');
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($contents) ; $i++)
    echo "<li>" . substr($contents[$i],1) . "</li>";
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Try running this:

```
<?php
$c = ftp_connect('ftp.mozilla.org');
var_dump($c);

$c = ftp_connect('abcdefg');
var_dump($c);
?>
```

You should get this:

```
resource(2) of type (FTP Buffer) Warning: ftp_connect()

[function.ftp-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\abc\def.php on line 5

bool(false)
```

Answer on : [How to get error if FTP server is invalid.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619903/how-to-get-error-if-ftp-server-is-invalid). Then you will know what kind of error appears.

Comment: Why so harsh ? I give him working example, maybe he figure out what he set up wrong based on this example.